# java - IDN.toASCII must protocol be removed before?

Tags: java, url, url-validation, punycode

I created an URL validator for my JSF webpage and now stumbled across a problem with domains where the first word (separated by dot) contains a non ASCII character.

I have following valid website url `http://testä.com`. Converting it to puny code using `IDN.toASCII()` creates invalid url: `xn--http://test-v8a.com`.

Should it not be `http://xn--test-ooa.com/`

I also checked it at german `de` domain manager DENIC which shows same invalid URL results.

https://www.denic.de/service/tools/idn-web-converter/

Is this a BUG in Java/RFC or am I missing something.

**Workaround**

When i remove the protocol at first it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is clear that this method only operates on domain name labels, so yes the protocol needs to be removed.

> A label is an individual part of a domain name. The original ToASCII
>   operation, as defined in RFC 3490, only operates on a single label.
>   **This method can handle both label and entire domain name**, by assuming
>   that labels in a domain name are always separated by dots.

Link to Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html#toASCII-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: Thanks for clarification